# Select specific column only from Laravel 5.2 Relation query not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-relations

So I have a query that I only want to get specific columns in a relation but is not working. I'm using Laravel 5.2 by the way. Here's what I have:

```
$job = Job::query()->whereId($job_id)
        ->with([
            'jobType' => function (Relation $query) {
                $query->select(['name']);
            },

        ])
    ->first();
```

If I do that, the jobType relationship returns `null` as seen below:

[image: job type relation]

And if I'll remove the `$query->select(['name']);`, it has the data from `job_type` table. How can I just successfully get specific column from a table?

Comment: @Remul have tried that but the same result.

Comment: Did you actually read it? you have to include the column that links jobs and jobType, otherwise how would you every know which job and jobType belong together, therefore eloquent returns null.

Comment: You need to select primary key and/or foreign key also

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This can.. To get the specific column you need a specific `jobtype`

```
$job = Job::query()->whereId($job_id)
        ->with(['jobType' => function ($q) use($jobType) {
                $q->where(// check the condition on jobtype table);
                $q->select(['name']);
            },
        ])
    ->first();
```

Comment: I think where clause is unnecessary, I have let it worked using the inclusion of the `id` column in the select clause.